# Getting Enum Name in spinner

Tags: java, android, enums

I am currently working on month conversion in spinner. 
Here I am trying to retrieve the currentmonth("10") from system and passing the value of month to enum to get corresponding enum name("Oct").

I have spinner array string starting from Jan to Dec. 
when i try to get Position of Enum Name "Oct" in spinner, it returns blank. However when i tried hardcoding "Oct" in getPosition, it worked.   I am not able to find out why getEnumByString returns blank. Can anyone help me.

```
String tempMonth=String.valueOf(monthCurrent);
monthSpin.setSelection(adapterMonth.getPosition(MonthConversion.getEnumByString(tempMonth));
```

MonthConversion:

```
 public enum MonthConversion {

 Jan("1"), Feb("2"), Mar("3"), Apr("4"),May("5"),Jun("6"),Jul("7"),Aug("8"),Sep("9"),Oct("10"),Nov("11"),Dec("12");

private String mValue;

private MonthConversion(String s) {
        mValue = s;
    }

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return mValue;
    }    
    public static String getEnumByString(String code){
          for(MonthConversion e : MonthConversion.values()){
            if(code == e.mValue)                    
                return e.name();
          }
          return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Post your MonthConversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
if (e.mValue.equals(code)) . . .
```

instead of `==` to compare string values. The `==` operator tests whether two objects are actually the same object, not whether they have the same logical value. `equals()` tests whether the two strings have the same values: the same characters in the same order.

You might also consider simply indexing into the `values()` array:

```
int index = Integer.parseInt(code) - 1;
return MonthConversion.values()[index];
```

(with appropriate error checking added, of course).

Comment: Good Catch :).. thank u very much.. I made mistake using of `==` instead of equals. I changed back to equals. its working fine.

Comment: I also tried with indexing. it worked fine. I just typecast `MonthConversion.values()[index]` to string and returned